# find command argument -iname doesn't work from variable

Tags: bash, find

find command argument -iname doesn't work from script when it's being used in a variable

```
iname="-iname '*py'"
echo iname:   $iname
```

doesn't work:

```
find . $iname -exec grep "text" {} \;
```

works:

```
find . -iname '*py' -exec grep "text" {} \;
```

**EDIT**

**Solution:**

I followed @chepner's explanation, and did this in my real-world script (it's more readable than using arrays from my perspective)

```
inamecmd=-iname
inamearg=*py
find . $inamecmd $inamearg -exec grep "text" {} \;
```

etc.

Comment: and the question is "why" and "how to make it work"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you type it out in full:

```
find . -iname '*py' -exec grep "text" {} \;
```

`bash` uses the single quotes to recognize that you want to pass the literal string `*.py` as an argument to `find`. It then removes the single quotes; `find` does not see them.

When you use a variable:

```
iname="-iname '*py'"
find . $iname -exec grep "text" {} \;
```

`bash` expands `$iname` to the literal string `-iname '*py'`, but *does not* remove the single quotes. `find` receives the literal string `'*py'` as an argument, so only matches files starting with a single quote and ending with `py'`.

Quoting the expansion of `iname` wouldn't help:

```
find . "$iname" -exec grep "text" {} \;
```

This time, `find` would receive as a single argument the string `-iname '*py'`, rather than two separate arguments `-iname` and `'*py'`. `bash` only performs one round of quote removal; it does not do so again on the result of the parameter expansion.

The correct way to pass multiple arguments to a command in a single variable is to use an array:

```
iname=(-iname "*py")
find . "${iname[@]}" -exec grep "text" '{}' \;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `bash -c`:

```
bash -c "find . $iname -exec grep "text" {} \;"
```

OR **better use BASH arrays**:

```
iname=("-iname" "*sh")
find . "${iname[@]}" -exec grep "text" {} \;
```